# Sieve data based on the the data we are getting

Tags: java

I have the data in array with 2 columns: name and date.
I showed data using ngfor in list as well the table format.

HTML

```
<div>
  <p>select date range</p>
  <input type="date" (change)="changeFirstInput($event)"> - 
  <input type="date" (change)="changeSecondInput($event)">
  <span>
   <ul>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let o of obj">
    <li> {{o.name}} {{o.date}}</li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
  </span>
</div>

<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
     <th>date</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let o of obj">
      <td>{{o.name}}</td>
      <td>{{o.date}}</td>

    
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is ts file.
Where i'm able to console the data between the selected date range of list items in console.
Now, i can see the data in console.
But, what i actually want is, filter data directly in my page. that is in table based on the selected date range.
Please help me do this.

TS File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  public obj = [{
    name: "john",
    date: "20.03.2010"
  },{
    name: "ibrahim",
    date: "10.01.2003"
  },{
    name: "sathwi",
    date: "01.02.2009"    
  },{
    name: "riya",
    date: "17.03.2015"    
  }]
 pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;
  public date1: Date = new Date("2000-01-01");
  public date2: Date = new Date();
  changeFirstInput(e){
    this.date1 = e.target.value;
    console.log(this.obj.filter(o => new Date(o.date.replace(this.pattern,'$3-$2-$1')) >= new Date(this.date1) && new Date(o.date.replace(this.pattern,'$3-$2-$1')) <= new Date(this.date2)  ));;
  }
  changeSecondInput(e){
   this.date2 = e.target.value;
   console.log(this.obj.filter(o => new Date(o.date.replace(this.pattern,'$3-$2-$1')) >= new Date(this.date1) && new Date(o.date.replace(this.pattern,'$3-$2-$1')) <= new Date(this.date2) ));
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes:

1. Use another array called `display` that will be used to show the fltered out elements.
2. Each time the second date changes we reassign a new reference of the original array to `display`, else every time you filter out the original contents are lost.
3. Use this array to display the elements on the template.

.ts

```
  display = [];

  changeFirstInput(e) {
    this.date1 = new Date(e.target.value.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));
  }

  changeSecondInput(e) {
    this.display = Object.assign([], this.obj);
    this.date2 = new Date(e.target.value.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));

    this.display = this.obj.filter(o =>
      new Date(o.date.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1')) >= this.date1 &&
      new Date(o.date.replace(this.pattern, '$3-$2-$1')) <= this.date2);
  }
```

.html

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let o of display">   <!-- change made here only -->
            <td>{{o.name}}</td>
            <td>{{o.date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Only replace the HTML portion of the table from my answer. The rest remains the same.

Comment: [Working stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-zbfuc4.stackblitz.io).